# systemd からのサービス起動時にHOME環境変数を設定したい

Tags: linux, amazon-linux, systemd

AWS EC2 Amazon Linux2 上で python のプログラムを ec2-user 権限で自動起動したいです

`/etc/systemd/system/test.service`　の中に

```
User=ec2-user
```

をかいたところ起動ユーザは ec2-user で動くようになったのですが
`.aws/config` が読み込めず AWS リソースへのアクセスがエラーになります
おそらく HOME という環境変数が存在しないせい？かと思うのですが

```
[Service]
ExecStart=HOME=/home/ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.pyenv/shims/python -u /var/www/test/current/scripts/test.py
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user
```

と書いてみても

```
Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: ...
```

となってサービスファイルの書き方的にダメ見たいです

完全に ec2-user と同じ環境状態で自動起動を行うにはどうすればいいのでしょうか

ec2-user でログインし状態であればカレントディレクトリに関係なく

```
python absolute_path/test.py
```

で実行できます

OS: Amazon Linux2 です

Comment: 先程と同様に Ubuntu での話になりますが、`systemd.exec(5)` に `ENVIRONMENT` という項目があって("Sets environment variables for executed processes.")、設定例が記載されています。

Comment: 思いつきですが、`HOME=/home/ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.pyenv/shims/python -u /var/www/test/current/scripts/test.py`をスクリプトとして、shを起動してはいかがですか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`systemd.service`(5) の `ExecStart` (など) はシェルスクリプトを利用せずに直接起動 (`exec`(2)) されます。なのでシェルの構文 (シェルスクリプト) を書きたい場合は `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '<シェルスクリプト>'` のような書き方をする必要があります。サービスプロセス向けに環境変数を設定したいだけであれば、`sh` を利用せずに `Environment="HOME=/home/ec2-user"` を追加するだけで充分かと。